# Wordpress error 500 after placing code

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-500

I'm working on my first project on a Wordpress website. Ik make in my theme map a map with a file in it like ***************/rb-delete-all-transient.php.

Now when i put `echo "test";` in it the there is no problem and i see test in the browser.

If i put the code below than i get a 500 error and i have now idea what to do now.

Anybody a idea ?

```
class RB_Delete_All_Class {

 public function __construct() {
   add_action( 'init', 'rb_delete_all_transients' );
 }

 public function rb_delete_all_transients() {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $wpdb->options . ' WHERE option_name LIKE "_transient_%"';
    $wpdb->query($sql);
 }
}

$rbdeleteallclass = new RB_Delete_All_Class ();
```

Comment: can you echo `$wpdb->options` and paste the result?

Comment: If i do this then i get nothing on  my screen and if i use var_dump( $wpdb->options ); the i get NULL